# AWS SAM: can we use a already existing api in aws sam template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, templates, sam

I have a lambda function that needs to be triggered via Amazon API Gateway. Is there a way to include an already existing API (created using the AWS console) into AWS SAM template?

Comment: you can use AWS::Serverless::Api, have you checked this page? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-api.html

Comment: This will create a new api ,but I want to use an already existing api in template file

Answer (score 3):

SAM doesn't support the !ImportValue in the template yet.

[Issue on Github](https://github.com/aws/serverless-application-model/issues/1335)

On the GitHub of the aws/serverless-application-model there's an open PR for that feature

[See here](https://github.com/aws/serverless-application-model/pull/1152)

If you want you could help and contribute to that PR so then you could start using !ImportValue in your SAM template.yml

Else, I suggest you go with the old way, you create a CI/CD with a CloudFormation template that can use the !ImportValue and is linked to an S3 bucket where your lambda function code lives.

[Examples of Cloudformation Templates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-function.html)

## Update

SAM CLI now support the !ImportValue, the issue on Github is closed.

You can use it as follow

```yaml
# You need to export the resource that you want to use in another template first

# This goes at the end of your template.yml file, after the Resources

# template.yml in the first repo
Outputs:
    myExportedResource:
        Value: !Ref TheResource
        Export:
            Name: !Sub "{environment}-nice-export-name"


# template.yml in the second repo (This obviously goes in Resources)
    MyLambda:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
        Properties:
            FunctionName: awesome-lambda
            CodeUri: ./dist
            Handler: this-file.handler
            Role: !GetAtt LambdaRole.Arn
            VpcConfig:
                SecurityGroupIds:
                    - !GetAtt SecurityGroup.GroupId
                SubnetIds:
                    - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${environment}-nice-export-name"
```

You can use it exactly as a normal cloudformation template

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html

Note that here I used Fn:ImportValue because I needed to use !Sub but if you don't need to reference a parameter in your import value simply use !ImportValue

Comment: Any documentation on how exactly can we use the `!ImportValue`?

Comment: @Mooncrater I updated my response with a code example. You can use it exactly like a normal cloudformation `!ImportValue`. Make sure to have the latest sam cli version. You can check the version by typing `sam --version` in your shell. make sure to at least the version 1.24.1

Comment: @Mooncrater AWS docs here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html