Can AWS SAM be used for an existing CloudFormation stack?
I have an existing CloudFormation stack. Now I want to use AWS SAM for it. However, I didn't find in the docs how to use it for an existing stack rather than a new one. So the question: is it possible to use AWS SAM for an existing CloudFormation stack?

Yes, SAM CLI supports the !ImportValue.
This is a duplicate question. You can view the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63232730/aws-sam-can-we-use-a-already-existing-api-in-aws-sam-template

This question is completely different. I don't want to import existing resources to a new stack, I want to manage the stack itself with SAM.

In that case the short answer is no. You can refer to this Github discussion for more information: https://github.com/aws/serverless-application-model/discussions/3536

Well I think its doable, just give a try to import existing resources, and can update them using SAM. You can download the whole stack template file from CloudFormation, please check
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/generate-IaC.html if it helps

The short answer is no.
You can refer to this Github discussion for more information: github.com/aws/serverless-application-model/discussions/3536
Here is the detailed answer:
"SAM templates are deployed using AWS CloudFormation which does not support modifying existing resources created "outside" of this CloudFormation stack. For example, adding S3 trigger to an existing bucket will require SAM to add a NotificationConfiguration property to the bucket. Since CloudFormation can't modify resources created outside of stack, this is a no go with SAM. If your requirement falls under this umbrella, then it is not possible to support it in SAM today.
Technically speaking, this behavior is out of bounds for native CloudFormation resources, but we can always implement "custom resources" which do this for you. Custom Resources are Lambda functions that can make relevant API calls without being limited by CloudFormation's native constraints.
Keeping this tracking issue open to collect all requirements for modifying existing resources. If this gathers enough steam, SAM can automatically create and maintain these custom resources to do the job for you."
